# Creating this XML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I have used `XmlDocument` before to generate basic Xml before, however I am struggling to recreate the following XML via code. The main problem seems to be around adding the namespaces to the description section.

How do I create the following example XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pndsdc:description
         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
         xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
         xmlns:pndsterms="http://purl.org/mla/pnds/terms/"
         xmlns:pndsdc="http://purl.org/mla/pnds/pndsdc/"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://purl.org/mla/pnds/pndsdc/
                             http://www.ukoln.ac.uk/metadata/pns/pndsdcxml/2005-06-13/xmls/pndsdc.xsd"
>
    <dc:identifier encSchemeURI="http://purl.org/dc/terms/URI">http://example.org/my/docs/12345/</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title xml:lang="en">Everything you wanted to know about identity, but were afraid to ask</dc:title>
    <dc:description xml:lang="en">The article provides a summary of the 2003 White Paper on identity cards for the UK
    with a critique from the perspective of several national and international civil liberties organisations.</dc:description>
    <dc:subject>Identity cards</dc:subject>
    <dc:subject>Civil liberties</dc:subject>

    <dc:subject>Human rights</dc:subject>
    <dc:type encSchemeURI="http://purl.org/dc/terms/DCMIType" valueURI="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/Text">Text</dc:type>
    <dcterms:license valueURI="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/uk/" />
    <dcterms:rightsHolder>The National Campaign Against Identity Cards</dcterms:rightsHolder>
    <dcterms:spatial encSchemeURI="http://purl.org/dc/terms/TGN">World, Europe, United Kingdom</dcterms:spatial>
</pndsdc:description>
```

Code can also be [found here online](http://www.ukoln.ac.uk/metadata/pns/pndsdcxml/2005-06-13/xml/ex0.xml).

Comment: I'd recommend using Linq to XML and its XDocument class if you can. Creating XML with namespaces is a lot easier.

Comment: You should ask a more direct question. What have you got already? What do you struggle with specifically?

Comment: I'm with Peter, I don't see what the difficulty is here, so other than writing the complete code to write the above document, how can someone answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about creating namespace declarations.  Just make sure that every element that you create is in the right namespace.  The `XmlDocument` will create the namespace declarations for you.  So:

```
string pdnsdcUri = "http://purl.org/mla/pnds/pndsdc/";
string dcUri = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
...
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement description = d.CreateElement("pdnsdc", "description", pdnsdcUri);
d.AddChild(description);
XmlElement identifier = d.CreateElement("dc", "identifier", dcUri);
description.AddChild(identifier);
```

and so on.  It's usually easier to create a `Dictionary<string, string>` containing the namespaces keyed by prefix, and then do something like:

```
XmlElement foo = d.CreateElement("prefix", "name", namespaces[prefix]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [**`XMLWriter`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

I think this is the part you are looking for:

> XmlTextWriter maintains a namespace
>   stack corresponding to all the
>   namespaces defined in the current
>   element stack. Using XmlTextWriter you
>   can declare namespaces manually.
>
> ```
> w.WriteStartElement("root");
>  w.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "x", null, "urn:1");
>   w.WriteStartElement("item","urn:1");
>   w.WriteEndElement();
>   w.WriteStartElement("item","urn:1");
>   w.WriteEndElement();
>  w.WriteEndElement();
> ```
>
> The above C# code produces the
>   following output. XmlTextWriter
>   promotes the namespace declaration to
>   the root element to avoid having it
>   duplicated on the two child elements.
>   The child elements pick up the prefix
>   from the namespace declaration.
>
> ```
> <root xmlns:x="urn:1">   
> <x:item/>  
> <x:item/>  
> </x:root>
> ```

Comment: you might want to pick up and quote the corresponding English msdn article - most of everyone here doesn't speak German ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("dc","http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
...
```